# How can I change icon colors on different background colors?

Tags: color, website-design, readability

I'm using two solid icons on a card which has different background colors ( sometimes colorful images). I wanted to see if there's a way that I could make my icons visible and readable on all color tones.

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a background shape or shadow to the icon so there's good contrast? Change the color depending on the background? What are you expecting us to say? There's no magic to make any color have contrast with another color

Comment: You could look into the blend-mode css property and its various settings. It can make an icon visible on more background colors than normal color blending, but it can also make the color of your icons look very strange.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned readability, I guess there is some text on the icons. To make them readable when background is causing problem, you can add a solid circle or rounded square behind the main icons with some padding.

If you icons already have circle shape or rounded square like thing, the visibility issue can occur if background color matches the icon colors. In that case, you may want to add a contrasting stroke to the icons. Or give them a shadow.

See two images below:

[image]
[image]

**1**st image has 2 types of icons. Left one has already a shape (circle or square at least). Right one doesn't have. Both have contrasting issues with background (to some extent).

In **2**nd image, I used Stroke Color **to fix the contrast issue** in the icon on left, and for right one, used a shape behind icon with contrasting color ***to fix the icon***.

Having said that, there's no fix easy rule you can apply for all your icons and backgrounds, that would work. Most of the time you have to play with it if your backgrounds vary a lot according to requirements.